# Python define an action for an randomly chosen word

Tags: python, random, tkinter

I've written a script which chooses a random letter from a tuple and places it in a tkinter label.  Now I want to define specific actions for each letter, so for example, `"E"` might play a song.  How can I accomplish this?

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
import pygame
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *
from functools import partial
import random

pygame.init()

label=tk.Label()
label.pack()

def knopf(label):
    WORDS=("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
    label['text']=random.choice(WORDS)

button=tk.Button(text='Knopf', command=partial(knopf, label))
button.pack()

mainloop()
```

I tried to do it like Adam Smith, but I always get an Error.

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *
from functools import partial
import random
import pygame

pygame.init()

label=tk.Label()
label.pack()

def knopf(label):
    def do_a(): pass
    def do_b(): pass
    def do_c(): pass
    def do_d(): pass
    def do_e(): print("E")
    WORDS={"A":do_a, "B":do_b, "C":do_c, "D":do_d, "E":do_e}
    choice = random.choice(WORDS)
    label['text']=choice 
    WORDS[choice]()

button=tk.Button(text='Knopf', command=partial(knopf, label))
button.pack()

mainloop()
```

And here is the error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1470, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "C:\Python27\tester.py", line 20, in knopf
choice = random.choice(WORDS)
File "C:\Python27\lib\random.py", line 273, in choice
return seq[int(self.random() * len(seq))]  # raises IndexError if seq is empty
KeyError: 3
```

Comment: So, as an example, if "E" is a letter in the word, then you play a song?

Comment: I mean, that when random.choice chooses for exampel "E", then I play a song. So that I define an action for every letter in WORDS.

Comment: To fix your last error: replace `random.choice(WORDS)` with `random.choice(WORDS.keys())`, or `random.choice(list(WORDS))` as in @AdamSmith's solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write a function for each and dispatch to the various functions using a dictionary as with `WORDS[choice]()` below.

```
def knopf(label):
    def do_a(): pass
    def do_b(): pass
    def do_c(): pass
    def do_d(): pass
    def do_e(): play_song()
    WORDS={"A":do_a, "B":do_b, "C":do_c, "D":do_d, "E":do_e}
    choice = random.choice(list(WORDS)) # make the choice
    label['text']=choice # set the label
    WORDS[choice]() # do the action
```

Comment: @msw Thanks for the more descriptive text :)